# How to use IntelliJ bundled maven in terminal?

Tags: macos, maven, intellij-idea, config

Using MacOS Catalina. Installed IntelliJ. Maven works fine but in terminal mvn comand is not found. How to use IntelliJs maven in terminal?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Locating mvn installed using IntelliJ**

If you are specifically looking for `mvn` location, installed using IntelliJ on MacOS: `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/mvn`

**Executing mvn from terminal**

Now, if you want to execute `mvn` from terminal, you need to add to your path.

Assuming that you'are using zshrc, which is my case, you'll need to add the following command to ~/.zshrc

```bash
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin"
```

Now, reopen your terminal, and you can call `mvn`.

Obs.: Thanks to [nbro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71749764/13606187)

**Solving "Permission Denied"**

If you try to execute `mvn` and get "Permission Denied", you need to give execution permission:

```bash
chmod +x "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/mvn"
```

Comment: For Windows users, the corresponding location seems to be like:
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3

Comment: macos,  IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 installed via toolbox, the path is like this `~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/203.6682.168/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib`

Comment: e.g.

~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/212.5284.40/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin

Comment: I've got `permission denied` error when use this mvn, what could be the reason?

Comment: Is it like IntelliJ was installed by a different user and you are accessing it using another user? The Admin user can update the permission for your user.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I added the following 2 commands to `~/.zshrc` (which is what I am using)

```
export PATH="/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin:$PATH"

# Otherwise we get a "permission denied"
chmod +x "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/mvn"
```

Now, I can call `mvn` from the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Note that on **Windows**, from a Terminal console using CMD, you can execute *mvn* command using *CTRL+Enter* in IntelliJ :
[image: run mvn command from terminal]

As of the feature description under https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/07/run-ide-features-from-the-terminal/, this feature is also supported for **MacOs** with *Cmd+Enter*.

> **Run highlighted command using IDE** (default shortcut: Ctrl + Enter or Cmd + Enter)
>
> **Debug highlighted command using IDE** (default shortcut: Ctrl + Shift + Enter or Cmd + Shift + Enter)

Comment: This IDE feature does not use the context of the terminal, e.g., environment variables that have been set in the terminal are not considered when executing the command via this IDE feature.

Answer (score 2):

On linux (Ubuntu) when installed by toolbox, it might be something like this:

```
/home/<username>/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/211.7142.45/plugins/maven/lib/..
```

Answer (score 1):

In Windows You may find Idea location by env variable

```
PS > Get-ChildItem env:"Intellij IDEA"
Name                           Value
----                           -----
IntelliJ IDEA                  C:\Users\unknownuser\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.4\bin;
```

then use *M2_HOME* env variable to store related maven path

```
C:\Users\unknownuser\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3
```

and use it in the path

```
%M2_HOME%\bin
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'Intellij IDEA' because it does not exist.`

Comment: For me was in C:\Users\randomPerson\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\xxx.xxxxx.xxx\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin

Answer (score 0):

Mine under windows is under a weird location:
C:\Users\changeMe\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\222.3345.118\plugins\maven\lib\maven3

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on mac:

```
'/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/mvn' -version
```